# Guessing an ABAP PIN in 3 attempts using a loop?

Tags: abap

how can I pack this code in a loop where you have 3 attempts to guess the PIN?

```
DATA: pin_correct TYPE i VALUE 1234.

PARAMETERS lv_pin TYPE i.  

DO 3 TIMES.  
  IF lv_pin EQ pin_correct.
    WRITE 'Richtig'.      
    EXIT. " Aus der Schleife aussteigen
  ELSE.
   WRITE / 'Falsch, bitte nochmal eingeben'.
  ENDIF.
ENDDO.

IF sy-subrc NE 0.
  WRITE / 'Zu viele Versuche, Zugang abgelehnt'.
ENDIF.
```

---

---

---

But unfortunately, if I enter the PIN incorrectly once, it will be displayed as incorrect three times. So, I don't have three attempts."

I don't know how to read the variable again, I suspect it's with 'READ', but I also got an error."

Comment: Please don't post code with German texts, Stack Overflow is English only. You wouldn't need to post texts if you post a minimal reproducible example (`WRITE` is not needed to reproduce). If you use the debugger, you can see that your issue is only about `IF sy-subrc NE 0` and your question would be "Why `sy-subrc` is 4 after `DO` loop although `EXIT` was performed" (which is a wrong assumption)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is conceptually flawed. If you stop within the loop to "read the variable" again, you hand control back to the user, and the user might do whatever they want (i.e. click some other button, go to some other UI, ...). If they do so, how should your loop continue? Thus you can't just "stop a loop in the middle" (unless you are attaching a debugger), instead user interaction evolves around *events*. Every time you press a button or enter some data, an event is triggered, the UI is blocked and the server does it's processing. Then at some point execution ends and control is handed back to the user. Then when they enter some data again, another event is triggered. Each action has one *event block* attached, which is executed for each respective event. Every *report* can have multiple event blocks, that share all variables which are initialized when the report is opened and are thrown away when the report is closed.
You have created a simple report called [*selection screen*](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-us/abenselection_screen_overview.htm), which has [two possible event blocks](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-us/abenabap_processing_blocks.htm), namely `INITIALIZATION` which is executed once when the report is opened, and `START-OF-SELECTION` which is executed whenever you submit the form. By omitting these, the code in the selection screen is implicitly in `START-OF-SELECTION`.

So what you want to do is to keep a state (variable) across all events that keeps the count, then decrement that variable whenever the submit event is triggered, and eventually block if the count reaches 0:

```
* --------- Declaration of Variables ---------------
DATA:
  retries_left TYPE i.

* --------- Description of the Selection Screen ----
PARAMETERS:
  pin TYPE i.

* --------- Initialization Event -------------------
INITIALIZATION.
  retries_left = 3.

* --------- Submit Event ---------------------------
START-OF-SELECTION.
  retries_left = retries_left - 1.
  
  IF retries_left <= 0.
    " TODO
  ENDIF.

  IF pin <> 1234.
    " TODO
  ENDIF.

  " Pin entered successfully, continue execution
```

---

Some additional remarks:

- Dynpros were designed in the mainframe era and worked relatively well in the Desktop PC era, but they won't work anymore in times of smartphones, smartwatches, ... It just doesn't make sense to tightly couple your UI with your processing logic these days. ABAP is (slowly) moving to be a backend-only language, so I would not invest too much time in working with Dynpros.
- In case you want access control for a screen, I would strongly suggest to use the existing user / role / authorization management of the ABAP Platform